# mongoid and kaminari throws undefined method page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, kaminari, mongoid3

When using kaminari with mongoid, I get the error

```
undefined method `page' for #<Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo:0x007fe48c195af0>
```

Not sure what is wrong. I even tried running

```
Item.page(params[:page])
```

and I get the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `page' for Item:Class
```

The gem is present in the Gemfile. Double checked.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `mongoid`, in that case add to the Gemfile `will_paginate_mongoid gem` and run `$ bundle`

More info can be found [here](https://github.com/lucasas/will_paginate_mongoid) and [here](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/mongoid.rb).